# Read dynamic json data in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express server.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var json = require("./sample.js")
app.use("/", (req, res)=>{
  console.log("----------->", JSON.stringify(json));
  res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(json));
});

app.listen(2222,()=>{
  console.log(`Listening on port localhost:2222/ !`);
});
```

sample.js

```
var offer = {
"sample" : "Text",
"ting" : "Toing"
}

module.exports = offer ;
```

Once i execute the server.js file, it fetches the json data from sample.js file. If I update the data of the sample.js while the server.js is still executing I dont get updated data. Is there any way
 to do the same, without stopping the execution of server.js.

Comment: why is json file have js extension?. if you have json extension, you can do something like this: const jsonObj = require('./sample.json')  and access the keys by jsonObj.key1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, you have to read the file every time a request occurs (or cache it for a time, for a bit better performance).

The reason why `require` does not work is that NodeJS automatically caches modules for you. So even if you would require it inside the request handler (in the `use`), it won't work.

Because you cannot use `require`, it won't be convenient (or performant) to use a module. So your file should be in JSON format instead:

```
{
   "sample" : "Text",
   "ting" : "Toing"
}
```

To read it, you have to use the `fs` (file system) module. This allows you to read the file from disk every time:

```
const fs = require('fs');
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // To read as a text file, you have to specify the correct 
  // encoding.
  fs.readFile('./sample.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {  
    // You should always specify the content type header,
    // when you don't use 'res.json' for sending JSON.  
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(data)
  })
});
```

It is important to know, that now `data` is a string, not an object. You would need `JSON.parse()` to get an object.

Also `use` is not recommended in this case. It is for middlewares, you should consider using `get` (as in my example), or `all` if you want to handle any verb.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the file at runtime:

```
fs = require('fs');

function getJson() {
  fs.readFile('sample.json', (err, jsonData) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('error reading sample.js ', err)
    }
    return(jsonData)
  }
}
```

}

make sure your sample.js is instead just a json object.

Comment: make sure your sample.js **is** instead just a json object.

Comment: `require` also reads it in runtime. however, the problem is, he read it only once and with `require`, which caches modules...